# Month is always January at date parsing

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format

i tried to convert a date String into a date object, but unfortunately the month is set every time to Jan and I can't figure out why.

```
    String date = "20190522T072424.000Z";
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMDD'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'");
    System.out.println(sdf.parse(date));
```

Output:  Tue Jan 22 07:24:24 CET 2019

Comment: Try with lowercase `dd`, `DD` is for Day in year so the 22th day in the year is in january. [Check the SimpleDateFormat doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). This is just a typo, voting to close.

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I have no idea about Jan but your parser is wrong in general. Z at the end of time is UTC timezone. You parse it as constant text and get CET timezone. It is wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't use the obsolete `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use the new Java Date and Time API, available in the `java.time` package, instead.

Comment: Funnily your string is in ISO 8601 format, and while the classes of java.time generally parse ISO 8601 format without any explicit formatter, they don’t accept this variant. However, `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSX")`  parses your string.

Comment: What @MCEmperor said, except java.time isn’t actually brand new, it’s been around for 5 years. There really isn’t any excuse for not using it in 2019.

Comment: What @OleVV said, there's absolutely no excuse not to use it. [Here's what's wrong with the old classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

Answer (score 0):

As [AxelH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4391450/axelh) said, the format DD is for day of the year. If you use `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS'Z'` you will print Wed May 22 07:24:24 WEST 2019.

For reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html